# Statistics Question | Regression Analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, anova

I am trying to analyze a online food delivery usage for a company in COVID period. The data is time series data including 10 years. We have daily total amaount of order for food delivery (numbers). Different policies have been applied during Covid. These policies are work from home, shops closed, education stopped. These policies are defined in the data set as a binary values (0 and 1).

```
Data Structure
 $ date                           : Date[1:3234], format: "2010-07-30" "2010-07-31" "2010-08-01" ...
 $ total_revenue                  : num [1:3234] 6043 2423 8043 5431 1075 1019 3342 1940 4459 963 ...
 $ schools_closed                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ shops_closed                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ wfh                            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day                            : Factor w/ 7 levels "Fri","Mon","Sat",..: 1 3 4 2 6 7 5 1 3 4 ...
 $ month                          : Factor w/ 12 levels "Apr","Aug","Dec",..: 6 6 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ year                           : Factor w/ 10 levels "2010","2011",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I want to analyze the effect of covid policies on total revenue.

I did linear regression analysis considering only wfh, school_closed and shops_closed. Then, I tried to add yearly, monthly and daily effect on the analysis. But, when I combine the covid measure with time, I feel like I overlooked the data.

Can we use repeated measure analysis to see seasonal effect? And how do I properly check the effect of time: day, month, year?

Comment: I am not sure what "overlooked the data" is supposed to mean.  (It is also unclear how 10 years starting in 2010 manages to include Covid years.)   You might consider removing `year` from the analysis as it is really a numerical variable closely correlated with date (and in 2020 with lockdown measures). But (at least before Covid) you should be able to do seasonal analysis, telling you the effects of days-of-the-week and month-of-the-year together with a trend and some random noise.  You then get the shock of Covid and the lockdown measures which no doubt affected revenues.

Comment: Have you done any descriptive analysis at all?

Comment: Actually, I am working on only descriptive analytics.  I just want to see effects of the covid measures and its interaction of yearly, monthly, daily variables. And I made a mistake in years. It should be 14 years.